# Apache CXF Dynamic Client creation

Tags: java, cxf

I am trying to use Apache CXF to talk to a unknown web service. I have followed the [Dynamic Client example](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/dynamic-clients.html) from Apache.

```
    JaxWsDynamicClientFactory factory = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
    Client client = factory.createClient(wsdlURL.toExternalForm(), SERVICE_NAME);
```

This was working but now i am getting this exception when calling createClient():

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create schema compiler
    Caused by:
     javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
     - with linked exception:
     [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/tools/internal/xjc/api/XJC]
```

This looks similar to an [existing bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-2339). I am using DOSGi singlebundle 1.2 which includes cxf-minimal-2.2.9.jar; meaning the bug should be fixed in the version I'm using. the jaxb-api is included in my Apache CXF distribution which upon inspection contains jaxb-xjc.

Can anybody provide me some insight as to what I'm doing wrong? I swear this used to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/tools/ " is often occurs if you use JRE in your IDE intead of JDK.
Make sure, you use JDK in IDE (e.g. eclipse)

Answer (score 4):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

resolved problem

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to include the cxf-rt-core in your Maven dependencies.